# nspredicate questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nspredicate

I tried applying `NSPredicate` with core data, but how to apply it with `NSMutableArray` of classes?

I mean: I have `NSMutableArray` containing objects of class that have fields. How do I select the object with name test for example?

Another question: can I use `NSPredicate` to simulate the following SQL statement?

```
where field1 in ('A', 'B')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I select the object with name test

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", @"test"];
NSArray *filtered = [arrayOfObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

> can I use `NSPredicate` to simulate the following SQL statement?

Yep!

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"field1 IN %@", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil]];
NSArray *filtered = [arrayOfObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```